# Need BigQuery SQL query to collect time on page from Google Analytics data

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

can anyone help with a BIgQuery SQL query to extract the time on page for a specific page from Google Analytics data please?

For every visitorId who has visited a particular page I would like the time on page for that page. This is so that I can calculate the median time on page rather than the mean.

I'm assuming that the visitorId, hits.hitsNumber and hits.time dimensions will be needed. Also that somehow the hits.time for the hit where the page was viewed will need to be subtracted from the hits.time of the following hit.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  fullVisitorId,
  hits.page.hostname,
  hits.page.pagePath,
  hits.hitNumber,
  hits.time,
  nextTime,
  (nextTime - hits.time) as timeOnPage
FROM(
  SELECT
    fullVisitorId, 
    hits.page.hostname,
    hits.page.pagePath,
    hits.hitNumber,
    hits.time,
    LEAD(hits.time, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitNumber ORDER BY hits.time ASC) as nextTime
  FROM [PROJECTID:DATASETID.ga_sessions_YYYYMMDD]
  WHERE hits.type = "PAGE"
)
```

The key to this code is the `LEAD()` function, which grabs the specified value from the next row in the partition, based on the `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` qualifiers.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, @andre622. This is very helpful. One question: Shouldn't we add
`code` where hits.type='PAGE' `code`
to ensure we are calculating time between pages and not all hits?

Comment: What happens on the last pageview in the session? According to this query, the nextTime would be NULL and then (NULL - hits.time) as timeOnPage that comes out to NULL?

Comment: Looks like GA doesn't count the time on page for the last page of a session (which is considered an exit) - so above is a moot point.

Answer (score 0):

To Account for last page time, this query can be used, and it will give zero time on last page,since BQ doesn't have way to calculate time spent on last page, but it will at least give zero instead of null.

```
SELECT 
  fullVisitorId,
  hits.page.hostname,
  hits.page.pagePath,
  hits.hitNumber,
  hits.time,
  nextTime,
  CASE
    WHEN hits.isExit IS NOT NULL THEN last_interaction - hit_time
    ELSE next_pageview - hit_time
  END
  AS time_on_page
FROM(
  SELECT
    fullVisitorId, 
    hits.page.hostname,
    hits.page.pagePath,
    hits.hitNumber,
    hits.isExit,
    hits.time/1000 as hits_time,
    LEAD(hits.time/1000, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitNumber ORDER BY hits.time ASC) as nextTime,
    MAX(IF(hits.isInteraction = TRUE,hits.time / 1000,0)) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitStartTime) AS last_interaction
  FROM [PROJECTID:DATASETID.ga_sessions_YYYYMMDD]
  WHERE hits.type = "PAGE"
)
```

Comment: Also note that BQ/GA calculates time in milliseconds so you need to divide it by 1000, which is why its there.

Answer (score 0):

**Google Analytics 4
Time-Spent-On-Page**

```
SELECT
  user_pseudo_id,
  event_timestamp,
  ga_session_id,
  page_location,
  page_title,
  next_hit_in_the_same_session,
  (next_hit_in_the_same_session - event_timestamp)/1000000 AS time_on_page_in_seconds
FROM (
  SELECT
    user_pseudo_id,
    event_timestamp,
    (
    SELECT value.int_value FROM
      UNNEST(event_params)
    WHERE
      key = 'ga_session_id') AS ga_session_id,
    (
    SELECT
      value.string_value
    FROM
      UNNEST(event_params)
    WHERE
      key = 'page_location') AS page_location,
    (
    SELECT
      value.string_value
    FROM
      UNNEST(event_params)
    WHERE
      key = 'page_title') AS page_title,
    LEAD(event_timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params)
      WHERE
        key = 'ga_session_id')
    ORDER BY
      event_timestamp ASC) AS next_hit_in_the_same_session
  FROM
    -- Replace table name.
    `cloud-search.analytics_298504139.events_20220106` AS tableAlias
  WHERE
    event_name = 'page_view'
  ORDER BY
    user_pseudo_id,
    ga_session_id,
    event_timestamp ASC )
```